# Granting READER role access to a Subscription in Azure works fine in Postman, but not via Angular. Why?

Tags: azure, typescript, azure-active-directory, azure-resource-manager, azure-rbac

OK, I might be missing something simple here in Angular, but I could really use some help. I am trying to grant a Service Principal READER role to a Subscription programmatically. If I use PostMan, it works fine. However, when I send the same PUT request via Angular6 I get a 400 error from Azure that says:

> The content of your request was not valid, and the original object
>   could not be deserialized. Exception message: 'Required property
>   'permissions' not found in JSON. Path 'properties', line 1, position
>   231.'

The JSON being sent in both cases is:

```
{
    "properties": 
    { 
        "roleDefinitionId":"/subscriptions/{some_subscription_guid}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/acdd72a7-3385-48ef-bd42-f606fba81ae7",
        "principalId":"{some_service_provider_guid}" 
    }
}
```

I've captured traffic from both requests, and they show as application/json payloads on the PUT. So I am at a loss of what is deserializing incorrectly through Azure that is causing this error. I am trying to follow the REST instructions documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-rest

Any ideas what I am missing?

**UPDATE**

Adding the RAW REQUEST per request. I have replaced any sensitive data (access token, GUIDs etc) without changing anything else from the Fiddler output.

```
PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<VALID_SUBSCRIPTION_WAS_HERE>/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/7ec2aca1-e4f2-4152-aee2-68991e8b48ad?api-version=2015-07-01 HTTP/1.1
Host: management.azure.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 233
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Authorization: Bearer <VALID_TOKEN_WAS_HERE>
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json
Referer: http://localhost:4200/token/<VALID_DOMAIN_WAS_HERE>.onmicrosoft.com/graph
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9

{"properties": { "roleDefinitionId":"/subscriptions/<VALID_SUBSCRIPTION_GUID_HERE>/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/acdd72a7-3385-48ef-bd42-f606fba81ae7", "principalId":"<VALID_OBJECTID_HERE>" }}
```

Comment: Postman does some implicit encoding/character conversion based on the payload and content type you specified. The fact that it works in Postman means that your angular payload must differ slightly. Capture both requests with Fiddler or Postman’s proxy feature and use a comparison tool across both, including headers

Comment: Ya, I used Fiddler to inspect the body, and they both show the same JSON payload. There are indeed different headers between the browser and the desktop Postman app, but that shouldn't matter. There is also a postman tag header, but Azure should be ignoring that.

Comment: post your entire `request` from angular. Use the `Raw` tab from the Fiddler inspector. You can strip/obscure the Authorization header.

Comment: OK @astaykov, I have updated the original question with the RAW Fiddler dump of the request. Anything look out of place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I finally figured out what was going on here. It appears that I was posting to the wrong endpoint. I need to be posting to roleAssignment and not roleDefinitions.

So why did it work in PostMan? It seems there is a fallback from a previous version of the API that supported both when using legacy clients, which for some reason PostMan fell under. However, when posting via Angular it was actively rejecting it.

End result... send to "/Microsoft.Authorization/roleassignments/" with an API version later than "api-version=2015-07-01". All will work.